# Need Help, put PHP command outside quotations

Tags: php, iframe

So i have this piece of code:

```
<?php  $field['url'] = '<iframe src="http://xxx.xx/= **the_title();**" width="640" height="360" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>;'  ?>
```

I need to put `the_title();` outside the quotations, so PHP can read it.
Is it even possible to put it outside two quotations?

Comment: That depends a bit on what `the_title()` does. Does it return, or does it echo?

Comment: Both answers will work, if you are mindful of the comment from @ceejayoz.  Your the_title() function must return a string.  Utkanos's answer is a bit cleaner, as it doesn't require the use of an extra variable, however if you want to utilize interpolation and avoid the concatenation operator, you could indeed use Mjeebu's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is called concatenation and is a fundamental part of string building in any language. In PHP this is accomplished with the `.` concatenation operator.

```
"string etc ".some_func()." continuation of string"
```

Note you can use single or double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$title = the_title();
$field['url'] = "<iframe src='http://xxx.xx/=$title' width='640' height='360' allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true' scrolling='no' frameborder='0'></iframe>;"
?>
```